# Counting rows in a table based on multiple array criterias

Tags: arrays, excel

I am trying to count rows in a table based on multiple criteria in different columns of that table. The criteria are not directly in the formula though; they are arrays which I would like to refer to (and not list them in the formula directly).

Range table example:

```
Group   Status
a       1
b       4
b       6
c       4
a       6
d       5
d       4
a       2
b       2
d       3
b       2
c       1
c       2
c       1
a       4
b       3
```

Criteria/arrays example:

```
group
a
b

status
1
2
3
```

I am able to do this if i only have one array search through a range (1 column) in that table:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIFS(data[Group],group[group]))}
```

Returns "9" as expected (=sum of rows in the group column of the data table which match any values in group[group])

But if I add a second different range and a different array I get an incorrect result:

```
{=SUM(COUNTIFS(data[Group],group[group], data[Status],status[status]))}
```

Returns "3" but should return "5" (=sum of rows which have 1, 2 or 3 in the status column and a or b in the group column)

I searched and googled for various ideas related to using sumproduct or defining arrays within the formula instead of classifying the whole formula as an array but I was not able to get expected results via those means.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `group` and `status` criteria are a different number of values (2 values for `group`, but 3 values for `status`), I'm not sure you can do this in a single formula.  Best way I know of to do this would be to use a helper column (which can be hidden if preferred).

Put this **array** formula in a helper column and copy down the length of your data (array formulas must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=AND(OR(data[@Group]=group[group]),OR(data[@Status]=status[status]))
```

And then get the count with: `=COUNTIF(helpercolumn,TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks tigeravatar. I am afk at the moment, I'll try it as soon as get the chance.

Comment: Works like a charm and I understand the way you solved the challenge with the and/or helper column. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a slightly different approach, using Power Query / Power Pivot.

Name your tables `Data`, `Group` and `Status`, then create the following query, named `Filtered Data`:

```
let
    tbData = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Data"]}[Content],
    tbGroup = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Group"]}[Content],
    tbStatus = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Status"]}[Content],
    #"Merged Group" = Table.NestedJoin(tbData,{"Group"},tbGroup,{"Group"},"tbGroup",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Merged Status" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Merged Group",{"Status"},tbStatus,{"Status"},"Merged Status",JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Status",{"tbGroup", "Merged Status"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Status", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

`Load To` as connection only, and tick `Load to Data Model`

Now create a DAX measure:

```
Status Sum:=SUM ( 'Filtered Data'[Status] )
```

You can then use the following formula on your worksheet, to get the Sum of Status values, for rows matching the criteria specified in the `Group` and `Status` tables:

```
=CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","[Measures].[Status Sum]")
```

Simply refresh the data connection to update the value.

Comment: Eventually I want to move to PBi so thank you for your suggestion. I am afk at the moment but will check up on your solution as soon as I am able to. Thank you!